# Transpose rows in mysql with three columns

Tags: php, mysql, database

I have this table in mysql:

```
id | orden         | pacient  | per| exam  | value | condition  | date
---+---------------+----------+----+-------+-------+------------+--------------------
1  | 201208082001  | 20652598 | 0  | 1017  | 9.00  | 0          | 2012-08-08 09:28:21
2  | 201208082001  | 20652598 | 0  | 1018  | 4.80  | 0          | 2012-08-08 09:28:21
3  | 201208082001  | 20652598 | 0  | 4104  | 213.00| 0          | 2012-08-08 09:28:21
4  | 201208082002  | 2799592  | 0  | 1017  | 7.70  | 0          | 2012-08-08 09:29:21
5  | 201208082002  | 2799592  | 0  | 1018  | 2.40  | 0          | 2012-08-08 09:29:21
6  | 201208082002  | 2799592  | 0  | 4104  | 43.00 | 0          | 2012-08-08 09:29:21
7  | 201208082003  | 6058327  | 0  | 1017  | 9.10  | 0          | 2012-08-08 09:30:02
8  | 201208082003  | 6058327  | 0  | 1018  | 4.00  | 0          | 2012-08-08 09:30:02
9  | 201208082003  | 6058327  | 0  | 4104  | 840.00| 0          | 2012-08-08 09:30:02
```

What I need is this: each *set* of three rows has the same `orden` the same `pacient` and different `exams` and `values`. There is always a `CA` value, a `P` value and a `PTH` value. I need to check wherever a `pacient` have a `CA > 5.5` and a `P > 11` (and other bunch of things) in the original form of the table is very hard to get this quick and easy.

```
id | orden         | pacient  | per| CA    | P    | PTH    | condition | date
---+---------------+----------+----+-------+------+------- +-----------+--------------------
1  | 201208082001  | 20652598 | 0  | 9.00  | 4.80 | 213.00 |  0        | 2012-08-08 09:28:21
2  | 201208082002  | 2799592  | 0  | 7.70  | 2.40 | 43.00  |  0        | 2012-08-08 09:28:21
3  | 201208082003  | 6058327  | 0  | 9.10  | 4.00 | 840.00 |  0        | 2012-08-08 09:28:21
```

This transposed table will be in a view, I have tried with sub-queries but is extremely slow, so. I hope you could help me.

Comment: it'd be helpful if you explain exactly how the second table relates to the first. are you summing up the `value` column to producd `pth`? grouping? what's the grouping condition(s)?

Comment: Perhaps you can show the structure of the tables with an EXPLAIN statement for each.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You didn't provide many details about what gets placed in the `CA`, `P` and `PTH` columns but based on the data it looks like they correspond to the `1017`, `1018` and `4104` respectively. If so, you might be able to use an aggregate function with a `CASE` expression to convert the data from rows to columns:

```
select orden,
  pacient,
  per,
  max(case when exam = 1017 then value else 0 end) `CA`,
  max(case when exam = 1018 then value else 0 end) `P`,
  max(case when exam = 4104 then value else 0 end) `PTH`,
  `condition`,
  date
from yt
group by orden, pacient, per, `condition`, date;
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ce523/2).

This version does not use any subqueries to get the result.

Comment: This approach is exactly what I need. Thanks. And is really fast.